# Await function firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create function for Google Cloud tasks in firebase functions. I get logs:

```
1:01:36.743 AM
start
1:01:38.644 AM
Start google timer
1:01:38.653 AM
Final
1:01:38.767 AM
Function execution took 4341 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
1:02:04.541 AM
Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded at Object.callErrorFromStatus
```

I have been looking for information and guess that this is due to incorrect execution async/await requests. I don't have enough knowledge to understand this. How do I need to properly execute an asynchronous request? My code example:

```
exports.newTimer = functions.database
    .instance("plan-b-b98f3-default-rtdb")
    .ref("{userUID}/timers/{keyID}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const value = snapshot.val();
        await admin.database().ref(context.params.userUID + '/push').once('value',  (snapshotPush) => {
            functions.logger.info("start");
            return ScheduleRequest(value, snapshot.key).then(() => {
                functions.logger.info("success create cloud task", {structuredData: true});
            }).catch((e) => {
                functions.logger.error(e, {structuredData: true})
            });
        }, (errorObject) => {
            functions.logger.error('The read push tokens failed: ' + errorObject.name, {structuredData: true})
        });
        functions.logger.info("Final");
    });

const ScheduleRequest = async (timerKey, timer) => {
    const project = 'plan-b-b98f3';
    const location = 'us-central1';
    const queue = 'plnbtimers';
    const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient();
    const queuePath = tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue);
    const url = `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/endTimerPush`;
    const json = {id: timerKey};

    functions.logger.info("Start google timer", {
        id: timerKey,
        total: timer.created + timer.duration
    });

    const task = {
        httpRequest: {
            httpMethod: 'POST',
            url,
            body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(json)).toString('base64'),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        },
        scheduleTime: {
            seconds: timer.created + timer.duration
        }
    }

    return await tasksClient.createTask({parent: queuePath, task});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Schedule Request` function looks good to me but try refactoring `newTimer` function like this:

```
exports.newTimer = functions.database
    .instance("plan-b-b98f3-default-rtdb")
    .ref("{userUID}/timers/{keyID}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        try {
            const value = snapshot.val();
            const snapshotPush = await admin.database().ref(context.params.userUID + '/push').once('value')
            // if (!snapshot.val()) return false
            functions.logger.info("start");
            await ScheduleRequest(value, snapshot.key)
            functions.logger.info("success create cloud task", { structuredData: true });
            return null
        } catch (errorObject) {
            functions.logger.error('The read push tokens failed: ' + errorObject.name, { structuredData: true })
            functions.logger.info("Final");
            return null
        }
    });
```

What are you fetching the `snapshotPush` for? Are you just checking if the value exists? If yes, uncomment the line that returns false.

Another important thing is that you must [terminate background functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#terminating_background_functions). Notice the `return null` statements. Alternatively you can return that promise as well like this:

```
return ScheduleRequest(value, snapshot.key)
```